# Php return data from database into a table which contains an onlclick button function

Tags: php, ajax

Basically i have  php code which retrieves data from a database into a table, i have placed a button with an onclick function in each row of the table. the buttons aren't working cause its php(server side).

Could someone point me in the right direction to do this? retrieve data from Db put into a table with a button in each row with an onclick event.

thanks

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey the question is very clear

Comment: @bizzare: No it's not, what information are you trying to retrieve? What do you want to do with it? What do the buttons do exactly?

Comment: @Truth these are not important information we just know some information must be retrieved and then we must delete or retrieve them with an anchor ! ok ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use an anchor in each row and assign a class name for example  :

```
<a class="delete_btn" href="index.php?action=fetchdta&id=1">Delete</a>
```

then use this jquery code on top of your page in a script tag :

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
        $('.delete_btn').click(function(){
            var urlt = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({
              url: urlt,
              success: function(data) {
                              //do Everything you want
              }
            });     
            return false;
        });

</script>
```

Comment: Your answer hardly answers the question. You provide a very general approach to a very specific question, of which you don't know the details. Please refrain from posting answers like those.

Comment: @Truth why ? this answer is useful for this guy ! take it easy !this exactly what he want ! ok ?

Comment: hey just to say thanks this pointed me in the direction where i wanted to go with it